# Filter large dataset base on aggregation result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to do sort of an "Advanced Search" functionality with MongoDB. It's a sport system, where player statistic are collected for each season like this:

```
{
  player: {
    id: int,
    name: string
  },
  goals: int,
  season: int
}
```

Uses can search data across season, for example: **I want to search for player who scored > 30 goals from season 2012 - 2016.**

I could use mongodb aggregation:

```
db.stats.aggregate( [
 { $match: { season: { $gte: 2014, $lte: 2016 } } }
 { $group: { _id: "$player", totalGoals: { $sum: "$goals" } } },
 { $match: { $totalGoals: { $gte: 30 } } },
 { $limit: 10 },
 { $skip: 0 }
] )
```

That's working fine, the speed is acceptable for the collections with more than 3 millions records.

However, if the user just want to search for a larger seasons range, let say: *players lifetime statistic*. The aggregation turns out to be very very very slow. And I understand that MongoDB has to go through all the docs and calculate the $totalGoals.

I just wonder if there is better approach that could solve this performance problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can have pre-calculated data for past seasons and make two step query:

   a) get past data
   b) get current data
2. you could try to optimise indexes on that query
3. hardware: use SSD
4. hardware: more memory
5. introduce sharding to split load

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the direction. I surely will take a look at sharding to divide the load.


However, I have a question about pre-calculated data. I was thinking about this before, however, that would only solve the problem when we search for all time statistic. When user specify a custom range, instead of 2012-2016, they do a search for 2010-2013. We have no way of pre-calculated these custom ranges? Or I'm I missing something?

Comment: @ptgamr pre-calculation should be season based

Comment: a good sharding key for that should be a combination of player-season, as this will allow to spread the load,